# Compile remote project fails with "no such file or directory"

Tags: tramp, compile-mode

I'm trying to compile a remote project using **M-x compile**. I have the remote project directory open in a remote Dired buffer. M-x compile results in the following command:

```
Compile command: make -C 
/ssh:xxx@yyy.zzz.se:/home/bob/micke/projects/LCC/ clean
```

The command fails with the following error message:

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: 
"/scp:xxx@yyy.zzz.se:/home/bob/micke/projects/LCC/" -*-
Compilation started at Mon Aug 21 10:38:30

make -C /ssh:xxx@yyy.zzz.se:/home/bob/micke/projects/LCC/ clean
make: *** /ssh:xxx@yyy.zzz.se:/home/bob/micke/projects/LCC/: No 
such file or directory.  Stop.

Compilation exited abnormally with code 2 at Mon Aug 21 10:38:31
```

(I have masked the remote server user and name). I have passwordless log in setup on the remote host using a certificate, I use this without any problems outside Emacs.

I know the directory on the remote machine exist and I know the remote user and remote machine is correct (I have the remote directory opened in a remote Dired buffer).

Do I have to setup anything else when doing remote development and compilation?

Regards, Micke.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arguments of your `compile` command must not use remote file name syntax. It should look like

```
make -C /home/bob/micke/projects/LCC/ clean
```

Due to the remote `default-directory`, Tramp knows to run this on the remote host.